Is there a way to disable highlighting of search results in the current file when specifically using the search activity bar?
When doing a search of all files in the workspace using the search activity bar, VSCode will highlight all of the search results in the current file.
This is on top of anything that's being highlighted through other means, including the in-file search feature. It creates a lot of visual noise and makes it hard for me to parse what's going on. While I'd like to keep it highlighting search results when using the in-file search feature (i.e. the search field activated by pressing Command+F / Control+F), I'd rather it not highlight the search results listed in the search activity bar.
Is there any way to turn that off, but leave highlighting of other search results on?
(Note: this is not the same question as asking about turning off all search highlighting, or turning off selection highlighting. I'm specifically trying to turn off one kind of highlighting, from the search activity bar, while leaving the others on.)

Maybe you came from an experience with another editor that had this feature. I have seen so many related topics with Vim, and if that is true, this may help: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim

I'm sure that feature was never asked since it is not that bothering! But building a custom extension would definitely be possible. You can tweak so much if you decided to go on that direction, but you know it takes too much time

I don't think there is any direct option to do what you want. As you know the search across files and the find matches share a theme color so you can't disable one or the other.
One can try this.  Make these keybindings in your keybindings.json:
{
  "command": "runCommands",
  "key": "ctrl+f",           // whatever keybinding you want
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
        "args": {
          "query": "",
          "triggerSearch": true
        }
      },
      "actions.find"
    ]
  }
},

{
  "command": "runCommands",
  "key": "ctrl+shift+f",   // whatever keybinding you want
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs",
        "args": {
          "searchString": ""
        }
      },
      "workbench.action.findInFiles"
    ]
  }
}

Those will disable the find match OR the search match colors showing up by "nulling" either the find widget input or the search view input.  So at least you don't get both theme colors at the same time.
When you Ctrl+F the search match highlights disappear and when you do Ctrl+Shift+Ctrl the find match highlights are removed.  There may not be a better way to accomplish what you want.

This is a good suggestion, but my workflow has me keeping lists of results in the search activity bar as I edit files and search for other text within them. So I need to keep the search activity bar results around.

Mark's answer looks like it gives a good workaround (Note that if you want to have a user settings.json that works on all platforms, you'd need to make two copies of each- one with a when clause only matching Windows and Linux platforms, and one only matching macOS). I thought I'd answer why I don't think what you want is directly supported at the time of this writing. Take a look at

this code in src/vs/editor/contrib/find/browser/findDecorations.ts registering an editor decoration, FindDecorations._FIND_MATCH_DECORATION for find matches (from the find widget).
this code in src/vs/workbench/contrib/search/browser/searchTreeModel/fileMatch.ts registering an editor decoration, FileMatchImpl._FIND_MATCH

Notice how they both register className: 'findMatch',. And if you look at devtools of VS Code, indeed, you'll see that both the highlighting span for matches from the find widget and search view use the same class, "findMatch", which I'm pretty sure is eventually affected by the CSS rule here in src/vs/editor/contrib/find/browser/findWidget.css.
For VS Code itself to support you here, I'm pretty sure those two editor decoration definitions would need to use different CSS classnames. You could raise an issue ticket or PR for that.

If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

I'm considering creating a feature request, or even trying to implement it myself. If I do I'll certainly link to it here.

You can adjust the color for search highlight to make less prominent or invisible by adding settings to ur settings.json file.
for example:
"workbench.colorCustomizations"{
    "editor.findMatchingHoghlightBackground": "00000000"
}

it worked for me.

You mean editor.findMatchHighlightBackground, correct? Unfortunately that affects both in-page search results and results from the search activity bar. I just want to change the latter, not both.

While direct solution is not available, you can consider following workaround to reduce the visual prominence of search highlights from the search activity bar:
"workbench.colorCustomizations"{
    "editor.findMatchingHoghlightBackground": "#00000000",
    "editor.findMatchingHighlightBorder": "#00000000"
}

please note that this change will affect both in-file search highlights and search activity bar highlights.
